# How to estimate panel data where not all variables are correlated with the individual specific effect?

Tags: self-study, econometrics, panel-data, random-effects-model, fixed-effects-model

For an assignment in my masters course microeconometrics I am working with panel data. I need to model *log(wage)* with gender, race, number of weeks worked in a year, experience, years of education, etc. First I have to use a Fixed Effects estimator, then a Random Effects estimator and assess with the Hausman test whether the difference in coefficients is significant, the difference is significant so the consistent estimator should be the Fixed Effect estimator. So far so good.

The part where I am stuck for the last few days is the following. They ask to re-estimate the model when we suspect that *log(experience)* is 'endogenous'. Endogenous in the sense that it is correlated with the individual-specific unobservable effect (but not with the overall equation error).

I get stuck in that I don't know what the right estimation method is, my intuition would be to say that you can just use a Fixed Effects estimator, but because you are then doing the exact same as in the first part of the assignment that is not likely to be correct.

If we would have the normal model
$$
y_{it} = \alpha_i + X'_{it}\beta+  \epsilon_{it}
$$
Then for a Fixed Effect the regressors are correlated with the individual specific effect, $\alpha_i$, while for the random effect this correlation is assumed to be zero. In the part where I get stuck only some variables are correlated with the individual specific effect.

Since there is no estimator in our slides that is able to make this distinction (we covered First-Differencing, Within Estimator, GLS, Pooled OLS, Least square dummy variable) I searched the internet. The closest I got was a mixed effect model, which according to Wikipedia takes up random and fixed effects. However, when I read more about it it seemed as if this wasn't about the correlation between $\alpha_i$ and the regressors but an individual coefficient for a certain regressor
$$
y_{it} = \alpha_i + X'_{it}(\beta_{group}+\beta_{individual})+  \epsilon_{it}
$$
Another idea I thought of was to use GMM. If only certain regressors are correlated with the individual specific effect, $\alpha_i$ then you can construct moment conditions. Because there is no correlation between the 'exogeneous' regressors and $\alpha_i$ it should hold that $E[X_{'exogeneous', i}*\alpha_i] = 0$. I don't know if anything is wrong with my GMM idea, but I can't find it anywhere (and I searched pretty long already) so I doubt this is the way to go.

Since I am stuck here for a few days already and my friends don't know it either I decided to ask for your help! Hopefully you have some hints and tips I can follow. Also this is one of my first questions on stackexchange, if you have any tips how to increase the quality please let me know.

Thanks in advance!